# Delay rendering of frames in a stream angular 7

Tags: html, angular, stream, rendering

I'm trying to create an angular webpage that allow the visitor to see a live view from a webcam.
The stream consists of a sequence of frames (for example 10 frames per second).
A static URL is provided, the camera operating at a given address:port. So, I show the live view as follows.

```
<div class="row" style="width:70%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
    <img [src]="'http://localhost:5000/video_feed'"/>
</div>
```

It happens that there is a substantial delay in the rendering of each frame when it comes up.
In other words, what is captured by the webcam comes in a delay proportionate to the number of frames per second.

I tried the same in a simple html page and the live view seems almost in real time.
How can I decrease the rendering latency of each frame in my angular application?

Comment: Why not using HTML5 `video`?

Comment: it's a live view. I don't need a media player.